# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'system.threading.tasks.task bool'

Tags: c#, sql, linq, wcf

I have this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'system.threading.tasks.task bool'" in my service implementation code. Could you correct my code please.

```
public Task<bool> login(string usn, string pwd)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext auth = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var message = from p in auth.Users
                      where p.usrName == usn && p.usrPass == pwd
                      select p;
        if (message.Count() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to be specific whether you want this operation happen asynchronously or not.

As an example for `Async Operation` :

```
public async Task<bool> login(string usn, string pwd)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext auth = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var message = await (from p in auth.Users
                  where p.usrName == usn && p.usrPass == pwd
                  select p);
    if (message.Count() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you don't need it to be an Async operation, try this:

```
public bool login(string usn, string pwd)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext auth = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var message = from p in auth.Users
                  where p.usrName == usn && p.usrPass == pwd
                  select p;
    if (message.Count() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
`async` and `await` are compatible with .net 4.5 and C# 5.0 and more

Answer (score 17):

If you add `Task.FromResult`, you can fake it into compiling and working even though your method is not `async`. I had to do this when hooking up Identity, which is all `async`, to a legacy back end.

Example:

```cs
public override Task<bool> IsEmailConfirmedAsync(string userId)
{
  var profile = UserProfileType.FetchUserProfile(AtlasBusinessObject.ClientId.ToString(), decimal.Parse(userId));
  Task.FromResult(profile.EmailAddress.NullIfEmpty() != null);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `await Task.Delay(0);` and causing overhead with the cost of making the async state machine instead don't use the `async` keyword and do `return Task.FromResult(profile.EmailAddress.NullIfEmpty() != null);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain oh. ok. Fixed it.